# Trying to have access to route parameters inside group routing

Tags: php, lumen

I'm trying to have access to {module} inside my function, but it returns me the following error :

> Too few arguments to function {closure}(), 1 passed in /Users/Bernard/PROJECTS/myproject/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Routing/Router.php on line 62 and exactly 2 expected

Here's my code :

```
$app->router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($router) {
    $router->group([
        'namespace'  => $version,
        'prefix'     => "api/$version/{contest}/{module}",
        'middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\COMMON\DefineContest',
    ], function ($request, $module) use ($router) {
        dd($module);
        require __DIR__ . "/../routes/v1/{module}.routes.php";
    });
});
```

Comment: Enable facades and use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::parameter('parameter_name')`.

Comment: :'( Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::parameter() I did enable facades.

Comment: Oh sorry then, this works in Laravel didn't think it was unavailable in Lumen. If you want I can give an imperative answer to that using regex and plain php.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, it would be as simple as calling `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::parameter(paramname)` but since it is apparently not available in Lumen(looking at Lumen Router there are no methods or parameters for this use case), this is an imperative answer that does get the job done:

```
$version = 1;

$router->group([
    'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
], function ($router) use ($version) {
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $version,
        'prefix' => "api/$version/{contest}/{module}",
        'middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\COMMON\DefineContest'
    ], function ($router) use ($version) {
        $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        if (preg_match("/api\/$version\/(?<contest>\w+)\/(?<module>\w+)/", $url, $output)) {
            $module = $output['module'];
            dd($module);
        }
    });
});
```

I should point out that this code results in an extra step for every route which I don't think matters since it's not that heavy but something to note of.